# Unable to find compiled C++ functions in R package

Tags: r

I'm having difficulty integrating C++ functions into my R package. I'm following [Hadley's guide](https://r-pkgs.org/src.html) step by step, and I'm curious if perhaps it needs an update. I created a tiny test [package](https://github.com/eweine/rcpp_testing) for reproducibility.

To create this package, I follow these steps:

(1) Create the `call_times_two` function in `hello.R`.

(2) Call `devtools::document()`.

(3) Call `usethis::use_rcpp()`.

(4) Add the suggested roxygen tags to `R/rcpptest-package.R`.

(5) Add Hadley's `timesTwo` function to `src/code.cpp`.

(6) Call `devtools::document()` again.

(7) Build and reload the package.

No errors were encountered in any of the above steps.

Then, I attempt to call my `call_times_two` function as

```
# Expected output of 6
rcpptest::call_times_two(3)
```

However, when I call this function I get the following error:

```
Error in .Call("_rcpptest_timesTwo", PACKAGE = "rcpptest", x) : 
  "_rcpptest_timesTwo" not available for .Call() for package "rcpptest"
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that guide or version is outdated?  We have supported `Rcpp.packages.skeleton()` pretty much since Rcpp was first released.

##### Create

```
$ Rscript -e 'Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("rcpptest")'
Creating directories ...
Creating DESCRIPTION ...
Creating NAMESPACE ...
Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
Saving functions and data ...
Making help files ...
Done.
Further steps are described in './rcpptest/Read-and-delete-me'.

Adding Rcpp settings
 >> added Imports: Rcpp
 >> added LinkingTo: Rcpp
 >> added useDynLib directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp) directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added example src file using Rcpp attributes
 >> added Rd file for rcpp_hello_world
 >> compiled Rcpp attributes 
$
```

##### Install

```
$ R CMD INSTALL rcpptest
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘rcpptest’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
ccache g++-11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe   -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
ccache g++-11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe   -c rcpp_hello_world.cpp -o rcpp_hello_world.o
ccache g++-11 -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -o rcpptest.so RcppExports.o rcpp_hello_world.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-rcpptest/00new/rcpptest/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (rcpptest)
$
```

##### Use

```
> library(rcpptest)
> rcpp_hello_world()
[[1]]
[1] "foo" "bar"

[[2]]
[1] 0 1

>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what to do here? I tried running Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("rcpptest"). It ran successfully, but I'm still encountering the exact same error. It would be great if you could explain specifically what the issue is.

Comment: You may have other problems I cannot diagnose from afar. You will just have to trust me that I (literally and figuratively) typed the three commands shown above, in sequence, and copied their output.  Maybe try to get yourself onto another machine -- RStudio Cloud still gives a few hours/month in the free tier and actually try what I wrote just to make sure there is nothing funny on your machine?